# How to get 4 unique random numbers in range <0;9>?

Tags: c#

I want to get 4 unique random floating point numbers in the range <0;9>. How could I do that. Is it possible to do this with a single function so I don't need to generate random numbers in a loop?

Comment: You're asking for floats here, but your comments suggest you really want ints.  Clarify?

Comment: Here is an article on visual studio magazine about this: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/generating-distinct-random-array-indices.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var rng = new Random();
int first = rng.Next(10);
int second = rng.Next(10);
int third = rng.Next(10);
int fourth = rng.Next(10);
```

If you need four *distinct* values then you can do something like this...

```
var rng = new Random();
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).ToArray();
int first = values[0];
int second = values[1];
int third = values[2];
int fourth = values[3];
```

Note that if you needed to generate many numbers then a [proper shuffle implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) will give better performance than `OrderBy`: O(n) rather than O(n log n). If you only need a handful of numbers then `OrderBy` will be fine.

Comment: @Richard Knop: unique or random? The above code does exactly what you asked in your question.

Comment: "They need to be unique".  Then they aren't random, are they?

Comment: I have added word "unique" word to my question. They need to be unique (I don't want the same number twice) but random. Example: 0,4,5,8 or 3,1,7,6. 5,1,2,5 is not good.

Answer (score 6):

I am sorry but I could not resist

http://xkcd.com/221/

In that spirit you can do

```
r1=2.7;
r2=6.9;
r3=4.2;
r4=8.1;
```

I swear they are random

Comment: Good use of a classic

Answer (score 2):

> so I don't need to generate random numbers in a loop?

Since your range is so limited, you can generate a number in [0, 9999] and use decimal digit extraction. This will likely improve performance, but only very slightly. Personally, I would just use a loop.

```
int fourDigit = m_Random.Next(10000);
int first = fourDigit % 10; fourDigit /= 10;
int second = fourDigit % 10; fourDigit /= 10;
int third = fourDigit % 10; fourDigit /= 10;
int fourth = fourDigit;
```

The original poster has clarified that the numbers are to be distinct. This practically necessitates a loop at least somewhere in the code. However, I do not think it requires multiple calls to `Random`, by adapting the above.

**NOTE**: I am not sure if this incrementing technique is free of bias, if someone familiar with the mathematics behind random numbers would be so kind to analyze. Thanks.

```
int fourDigit = m_Random.Next(10000);
int first = fourDigit % 10; fourDigit /= 10;
int second = fourDigit % 10; while (second == first) second = (second + 1) % 10; fourDigit /= 10;
int third = fourDigit % 10; while (third == first || third == second) third = (third + 1) % 10; fourDigit /= 10;
int fourth = fourDigit; while (fourth == first || fourth == second || fourth == third) fourth = (fourth + 1) % 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to get distinct random numbers in a given range:

```
var random = new Random();

int take = 4;
int rangeMin = 0;
int rangeMax = 10;

var randomUniqueNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(i => random.Next(rangeMin, rangeMax))
    .Distinct()
    .Take(Math.Min(take, rangeMax - rangeMin));
```

It would be nicer with an Infinite enumeration insted of Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue), but this does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
    Enumerable.Range(0, 9)
              .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())
              .Take(4)
              .ToArray();
```